# printing an array of arrays in objective C

Tags: objective-c

Sorry for the simple question, but I am self taught and know that there are gaps in my education.

To print an array in objective C, I believe is:

```
NSLog(@"My array: %@", myArray);
```

How can I print an array of arrays?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean an `NSArray` of `NSArray`s? Or do you mean something like `const char stuff[3][2]`? Because the two are very different things.

Comment: I meant an NSArray of NSArrays.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want this:

```
for(NSArray *subArray in myArray) {
    NSLog(@"Array in myArray: %@",subArray);
}
```

This will work for an array that has arrays nested one level deep.

Comment: Without looping. how do i access the array item directly? for example: char a[0] = 'x';  cout << a[0]; ?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to do anything different to log an array of arrays; the code exactly as you've written it will already show the contents of the sub-arrays.

That is, the following program:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
        NSMutableArray *sub = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int j=0; j<=i; ++j) {
            [sub addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", j]];
        }
        [array addObject:sub];
    }

    NSLog(@"Array: %@", array);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
Array: (
        (
        0
    ),
        (
        0,
        1
    ),
        (
        0,
        1,
        2
    ),
        (
        0,
        1,
        2,
        3
    ),
        (
        0,
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
    )
)
```

Clearly, it's already logging the sub-arrays just fine. If you want to control the formatting differently, you'd have to manually iterate them, but by default, the `-description` of an NSArray is little more than the `-description` of every object in that array, which includes all sub-arrays.

Comment: This is by far the best answer, as it is the simplest. If you have custom objects in the arrays, you can always override `NSObject`'s `-description` method to make it something more appropriate for that class.

Answer (score 2):

So I was embarrassed by the recursiveDescription thing, so I wrote my own as a category on NSArray. Note that this code will print out a description for an array of arrays to any depth. The description itself could probably use a bit more formatting than commas and newlines. Here you go:

```
@interface NSArray (RecursiveDescription)
- (NSString *)recursiveDescription;
@end


@implementation NSArray (RecursiveDescription)

- (NSString *)recursiveDescription {
    NSMutableString *description = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Array (\n"];
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    for (NSObject *child in self) {
        if ([child respondsToSelector:@selector(recursiveDescription)]) {
            [description appendFormat:@"%@,\n", [child recursiveDescription]];
        }
        else {
            [description appendFormat:@"%@,\n", [child description]];
        }
    }
    [pool drain];
    [description appendString:@"\n)"];
    return [description autorelease];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try logging the return value from `NSArray`'s `-description` method.

```
NSLog(@"My array: %@", [myArray description]);
```

Comment: That will be the same. The `%@` format specifier uses the result of the `description` method (or `CFCopyDescription()` for CoreFoundation objects).

Answer (score 0):

Moreover, for print all of elements

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
for(NSArray *subArray in myArray) {
    NSLog(@"[%d] %@",i, subArray);

    j =0;
    for(NSObject *element in subArray) {
        NSLog(@"[%d:%d] %@", i,j,element);
        ++j;
    }
    ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As much as I like how easy it is to log out an object in Objective-C, I didn't like seeing a 2D array as a very long list. I created a category on NSArray that prints out 2D arrays. It's not perfect and can be improved, but it has worked for me.

Header:

```
@interface NSArray (Logging)

- (void)log2DArray;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "NSArray+Logging.h"

@implementation NSArray (Logging)

- (void)log2DArray {
    NSMutableString *formattedString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSInteger longestSubarrayLength = 0;
    for (NSArray *subarray in self) {
        if (subarray.count > longestSubarrayLength) {
            longestSubarrayLength = subarray.count;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < longestSubarrayLength; i++) {
        [formattedString appendFormat:@"\n"];

        for (int j = 0; j < self.count; j++) {
            NSArray *tempArray = [self objectAtIndex:j];
            if (tempArray.count <= longestSubarrayLength) {
                [formattedString appendFormat:@"%@\t", [tempArray objectAtIndex:i]];
            } else {
                [formattedString appendFormat:@"\t"];
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", formattedString);
}

@end
```

Usage:

```
[myArray log2DArray];
```

Answer (score -3):

Or use `recursiveDescription` :)

```
NSLog(@"my arrays: %@", [myArray recursiveDescription]);
```

Comment: Where is this method documented?

Comment: It's not a documented method for `NSArray` because it doesn't work.

Comment: sorry, to my & googles knowledge that's just a plain wrong answer. I had to downvote. I'll change that if you can provide some explenation..

Comment: My bad. This is an undocumented method on UIView to dump a description of a uiview and its children; I (mistakenly) assumed that the method works on all cocoa touch objects, but it's actually just UIViews. Sorry!

Comment: Adding a different answer and leaving this here as a warning that this undocumented method only applies to UIView.